# Using Git to Figure out How Long a Line of Text Has Been In a File

Tags: git

Suppose we have a `file1.txt` in a git repository. Suppose this file has a line of text: `an old line of text`.

Is there a way to figure out, through git (or some other Unix utility?) how many days this line of text has been in this file?

Comment: `git blame -- <file>` will show which commit, who and when line was introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
datefrom=$(git log --pretty=format:'%cd' --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d' -S 'line to find' -- file1.txt)
```

That will result in date of commit that introduced that string.

- log searches commit history
- -S option finds first introduction of a string
- --pretty=format:'%ad' prints committer date
- --date=format obviously formats the date

Now from this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215934/whats-a-smart-way-to-count-the-number-of-days-since-x  you get:

```
echo $(( (`date +%s` - `date +%s -d $(datefrom)`) / 86400 ))
```

which results in number of days from introducing commit.

Ofcourse you can put everything in one command and make an alias,
or you can create git-command-name script and put it into user/bin folder and git will recognize it as git command that you can invoke with

```
git command-name 'line to find'
```